# Is there a way to exclude parts of mesh from curving when using curve modifier

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a way to make parts of a mesh thats bending according to a curve (curve modifier) rigid?
[image: ][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with only one pipe object, I guess you have to create 2 objects, a pipe segment and a joint piece, and use a different technique for each one to make them follow the curve: *Follow Curve* modifier and *Dupliframes*.

For the **pipe**:

- Create your curve.
- Check out its direction in *Edit* mode, if its bad press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- Put its origin at its beginning.
- Create your pipe segment, put it at the same point as the curve origin.
- Give your pipe an *Array* modifier so that it repeats.
- Give your pipe a *Curve* modifier so that it follows the curve.

For the **joint piece**:

- Create the object, put it at the same point as the curve origin.
- Parent it to the curve with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.
- Select the curve. In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > enable *Path Animation*, choose the amount of duplications with the *Frames* value, enable *Follow*.
- Select the joint object, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Duplication*, enable *Frames* and deactivate *Speed*.
- If you ever want to make every copy an object, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, to make each object unique, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Object and Data*.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didnt answer in so long. Your approach works thank you!

Comment: For me the elements dont follow the curve that nicely though

Comment: please explain what's the problem, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: My issue is that the curves I am using are are at acute angles so the joint pieces are not following the pipe properly. I uploaded my file where I was testing your method. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6009" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6009/)

Comment: so anyway it would not work with any method, I mean you can't ask for both pieces that follows and don't follow a curve, you need to choose, perhaps shift the joint position a bit so that it doesn't fall on a sharp angle

Comment: Yeah I think there is really no way around tweaking it manually. Thanks anyway for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Select those parts in edit mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to invert selection. Everything else is selected.

Create a vertex group. Assign the selected vertices to the vertex group.

Exit edit mode.

In Object mode apply the curve deformer and select the vertex group. It will be applied only to the parts you previously selected.